# AWS Windows 2012 R2 turning off IE Enhanced Security Configuration

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, internet-explorer, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to automate the disabling of `Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration` when launching a Windows 2012 R2 instance with AWS + `userdata`

I found some functions online that helped me do so. When I check in the `Local Server` under `Server Manager`, it says `IE Enhanced Security Configuration` is OFF. However when I launch IE, it says it's enabled. How can I have this disabled properly?

Here is the file I am passing into userdata for AWS:

```
<powershell>
    function Disable-InternetExplorerESC {
    $AdminKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
    $UserKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $AdminKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 0
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $UserKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 0
    Stop-Process -Name Explorer
    Write-Host "IE Enhanced Security Configuration (ESC) has been disabled." -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    function Enable-InternetExplorerESC {
        $AdminKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
        $UserKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $AdminKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 1
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $UserKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 1
        Stop-Process -Name Explorer
        Write-Host "IE Enhanced Security Configuration (ESC) has been enabled." -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    function Disable-UserAccessControl {
        Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" -Value 00000000
        Write-Host "User Access Control (UAC) has been disabled." -ForegroundColor Green    
    }

    Disable-InternetExplorerESC
</powershell>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might be one of those settings that only fully updates after a reboot?

Comment: have you tried adding the registry entries to a GPO?  That way they apply on login for admin/user.

Comment: @AngryCarrotTop sorry pretty new to windows systems. I am not sure what you are talking about =[

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and finally got this to work using the following userdata script:

```
function Disable-InternetExplorerESC {
    $AdminKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
    $UserKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $AdminKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 0 -Force
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $UserKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 0 -Force
    Remove-ItemProperty -Path $AdminKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Force
    Remove-ItemProperty -Path $UserKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Force
}
    
Disable-InternetExplorerESC
```

The trick is to actually delete the keys which then causes IE to actually disable ESC.